# How to deal with memory problem - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, camera, memory-management

I am getting 3 camera input to MATLAB with Infinite Trigger. But after minutes, cameras fill up my memory, and I have to restart MATLAB. How can I deal with this memory problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your question is a little vague, I'm going to guess that you are using the [Image Acquisition Tool](https://www.mathworks.com/help/imaq/getting-started-with-the-image-acquisition-tool.html) from the [Image Acquisition Toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/help/imaq/index.html) to acquire images. If so, you should check out the documentation on [logging your data](https://www.mathworks.com/help/imaq/setting-acquisition-parameters-in-the-image-acquisition-tool.html#bq98anh). Here's a screenshot of the Logging tab of the Acquisition Parameters Pane:

[image: Acquisition Parameters]

Notice that you have 3 options for logging data: **Memory**, **Disk**, or **Disk and memory**.

I'm guessing that you are doing **Memory** logging by default, meaning that the acquired images that you do not otherwise save will be logged to your system's memory. There is a limit on the memory available. By default, the tool sets the limit to equal all available physical memory when you first use the tool, or 1 GB, whichever is less.

You have two options that I can see:

- You *may* be able to set the **Memory limit** to be higher in the above GUI (assuming it is defaulting to the smaller value of 1 GB, and you actually have more memory available than that). I would try that first and see if it helps at all.
- You can use the **Disk** logging option to instead log your images to disk as an AVI file. This will give you the option to compress your images and reduce the amount of space they take up.

Answer (score 0):

Since your question is very vague, here is an equally vague answer: you will have to write some of the data that is accumulating in memory to disk and free up the memory for further input from the camera.

Comment: @Marc: I unreservedly confess to the snarkiness but I cling to the notion that I have provided a good answer to the question asked.  No one has posted a better one yet !